# Unable to run vmware tools with Ubuntu 16.04 on Workstation 14.1.2

Tags: 16.04, vmware-workstation, vmware-tools

I have installed VMware tools 10.2.5 successfully. When I reboot the VM for some reason VMware tools does not run correctly. I tried restarting VMware tools with `sudo /etc/init.d/vmware-tools restart` but I get the following message and VMware tools does not run.  [Failed message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbquH.png)

Comment: Why are using `init.d` when we have `systemctl` and what exact error message are you seeing?

Comment: Please copy and paste the errors into your post!